# Apache HTML reverse proxy how to resolve bad links

Tags: apache-http-server, webcam, reverse-proxy

I'm using Apache 2.4 reverse proxy to get remote access to my webcams. The reverse proxy is working fine.

- **External URL**: `http://example.com/camera1/home.asp`
- **Internal URL**: `http://camera1/home.asp`

However some links starting with `/`—absolute URI from site root and not relative URI—are not correctly rewritten by the reverse proxy.

Instead of being rewritten like this:

```
http://example.com/camera1/script.js
```

They are rewritten like:

```
http://example.com/script.js
```

Which is preventing the application to work properly. This is simply because Apache is not able to identify the link I'm using `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_http`, `mod_proxy_html`.

The automatic rewriting of the links provided by `mod_proxy_html` for HTML, CSS can not work in this context because the missed links are inside a minified JavaScript (compacted with no space and no indentation)

There is no need to say I can't modify the software of my webcams.

However, I have identified patterns which I could apply to make the correction if I would know how to introduce a regex to be applied before sending the reply back to the client.

Is there any way to apply some post processing to the application answer?

My config looks like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /cam1/ http://cam1/
ProxyPassReverse /cam1/ http://cam1/
<Location /cam1/>
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On 
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /cgi/ /cam1/cgi/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /advanced_data.asp /cam1/advanced_data.asp
</Location>
```

It is working fine for most of the situations, the response is correctly processed, I can see `/cam1` which is added. But some scripts are not working.

Comment: What does your Apache reverse proxy config look like? Look at [my general answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/486112) on setting up an Apache reverse proxy for possible tips and ideas. But in general you might do some research on [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) specifically [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) and [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#R=rewriterule). Those options allow you to create regex for filtering URLs just the way you describe.

Comment: I have added my reverse proxy configuration in my question<br>. If I'm correct the rewrite module is processing URLs only, not the response content

Comment: Thanks for adding! Should help others if I cannot look at out later when I have time. But please do not use HTML or HTML entities in your posts here. [Please read up on how this site use Markdown to format posts](https://superuser.com/editing-help); utterly no need to add any of the HTML you have added.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to replace one regexp by another in the response flow. I found all I needed there :
[mod_sed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_sed.html)
This requires to add the `mod_sed` module to Apache configuration.
`LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so`
So I can apply a `sed` command to the response flow.
I added theses lines to my original configuration:

    `AddOutputFilter Sed js
    OutputSed "s/\"\/cgi\//\"\/cam1\/cgi\//g"`

So the lines which are not corrected automatically by the `ProxyHTMLURLMap` instruction, are corrected by the sed instruction.
This is giving finally:

`ProxyPass /cam1/ http://cam1/
ProxyPassReverse /cam1/ http://cam1/
<Location /cam1/>
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On 
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /cgi/ /cam1/cgi/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /advanced_data.asp /cam1/advanced_data.asp
    AddOutputFilter Sed js
    OutputSed "s/\"\/cgi\//\"\/cam1\/cgi\//g" 
</Location>`